# Where does the behavior of document.cookie or window.location assignation comes from?

Tags: javascript

`document.cookie` or `window.location` are objects that have their `=` operator overriden so that when you try to change them, something different from a regular assignation happens.
`document.cookie` is even more surprising since `typeof document.cookie === "string"`.

Is it some built-in features of a few very specific javascript objects or is it something that can be reproduced with any kind of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, an object property (like `document.cookie` or `window.location`) can be defined to automatically invoke a getter or setter function when the property value is read or written to. Properties can also be flagged as writeable or not. This feature is used by browsers to implement the behaviors you are seeing.

As of [ECMAScript 5](http://es5.github.com/), you can define your own properties in this way using the `Object.defineProperty` function. Details and examples of how to use this can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). You can use this feature to, for instance, invoke some complex action when a value is assigned to a property of one of your objects.

Comment: Interesting! I never realized that `typeof` would return the type of the result of the `getter` and not the type of the object.